# How to type an arbitrary object or any of its keys as method argument

Tags: typescript

I've been trying for a bit to try to type the input method that serialises an arbitrary object recursively. I've used mapped types, generic arguments, recursive types (like the JSON type) without any luck ):

This is the method that I'm trying to get rid of the `any` in the argument:

```js
export function serialize(data: any) {
  if (data === null) {
    return '';
  }

  if (typeof data === 'object') {
    let serializedData = '';
    for (const k of Object.keys(data).sort()) {
      serializedData += k;
      if (data[k] !== null) {
        serializedData += serialize(data[k]);
      }
    }
    return serializedData;
  }

  return data.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "without any luck"?  `type Serializable = string | number | boolean | { [k: string]: Serializable } | null;` and `function serialize(data: Serializable): string {...}` seem to work for me.  What are you trying to allow/disallow that's not working out for you?

Comment: @jcalz I've tried something like that based on some JSON-like custom types that I saw but it doesn't work with a generic type in the call site: `function makeRequest<T>(data: T) { return serialize(data); }`

Comment: Well, you don't want that to work because `T` can be anything and I *think* you're trying to make `serialize()` only accept `Serializable` things.  So maybe you want a [constrained generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) like `function makeRequest<T extends Serializable>(data: T) { return serialize(data); }`?  That should work... although there's no reason for such a function to be generic anyway unless it's doing something specific with `T`.  I think you should detail your use case with a [mcve] of what does and does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom type guard in order to refine a value to a `Record<string, unknown>`.

```
const isUnknownRecord = (u: unknown): u is Record<string, unknown> =>
  typeof u === 'object' && u !== null

export function serialize(data: unknown): string {
  if (data === null) {
    return ''
  }

  if (isUnknownRecord(data)) {
    let serializedData = ''
    for (const k of Object.keys(data).sort()) {
      serializedData += k
      if (data[k] !== null) {
        serializedData += serialize(data[k])
      }
    }
    return serializedData
  }

  return String(data)
}
```

Comment: That adds more runtime code for something that I know is an object and I'd like to avoid that because this method is called on a hot path. I just don't know the shape of the object. If this is the only viable solution, I think I'll keep the `any` ):

Comment: The solution I posted is type safe (which is the point of using a type system in the first place), using `any` is not.